# Factory reset doesn't seem to work entirely

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4.  Performance playing videos is sluggish, and so are some calls and even camera functions, unless I'm on a Bluetooth connection.  In addition, after I perform a data wipe/reset from recovery mode, there are some files still present that I would suspect shouldn't be, like a file I placed in system/app.

What is happening here baffles me, but I suspect it may be something to do with the factory wipe not actually wiping everything, and some kind of internal memory corruption. [A thread on another site](http://androidforums.com/threads/internal-phone-storage-becomes-read-only.347685/) I found advised that internal memory can become locked as read-only.  Don't know if that's what's doing it.

Is there a way I manually delete the internal memory?  Being an S4, I can't put a custom recovery on it (thanks, AT&T), so I can't wipe things from there.  ADB complains that files are in use when I try to delete them.

Is there another way to delete these files?  Which ones can I safely delete?  Could this be another problem besides memory corruption? What can I do to troubleshoot?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You placed a file in /system/app? So you were rooted?

Comment: Quick info: factory resets don't alter anything in the **/system** partition.

Comment: Yes, I am rooted.  I didn't realize nothing in /system was reset.  So that explains the file not going away, but not the super laggy behavior in almost every app I have (anything with video, audio, the phone functions themselves, etc.)  What can I use to diagnose what's happening?

Comment: You can use Samsung Kies or SmartSwitch (I think Kies applies for the S4) to factory reset your phone. Because this will actually reset all your partitions (including /system)